# Transferring RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to transfer a Database in RavenDB to a remote server where I shall carry out some tests.

I am using version 960.

Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the import/export feature under the Tasks menu in the raven web interface.

Or if your of the command line persuasion look up [Raven Smuggler](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/backup-restore).

Comment: I exported it using the Web Interface under Tasks. How do I make this database run on my other Raven instance?

Comment: Under the same Task tab on your new instance Tasks -> Import